# Multiple legends in multiple graphs which is grouped bar line in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

When I looked my old projects, I noticed there is no code for a graph I included in my report.
Can you please help me how I get the graph below?

The data table,

| Score | variable | Actual | Pois |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | away | 0.316 | 0.314 |
| 0 | home | 0.228 | 0.213 |
| 1 | away | 0.366 | 0.363 |
| 1 | home | 0.313 | 0.329 |
| 2 | away | 0.205 | 0.210 |
| 2 | home | 0.248 | 0.254 |
| 3 | away | 0.081 | 0.081 |
| 3 | home | 0.137 | 0.131 |
| 4 | away | 0.016 | 0.023 |
| 4 | home | 0.055 | 0.050 |
| 5 | away | 0.009 | 0.005 |
| 5 | home | 0.003 | 0.015 |
| 6 | away | 0.003 | 0.001 |
| 6 | home | 0.006 | 0.004 |

The graph that I want to get,

[image: The required graph]

Thank you,
Veli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets you fairly close

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(within(df, variable <- factor(variable, c("home", "away"))),
       aes(Score, Actual, fill = variable, color = variable)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), color = NA) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Pois), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
            linewidth = 1.5) +
  geom_point(aes(y = Pois), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
             fill = NA, size = 4) +
  scale_fill_manual("Actual", values = c("#ffbca1", "#62c9c3")) +
  scale_color_manual("Poisson", values = c("#cd5c5c", "#006400")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 0:6) +
  labs(x = "Goals per match", y = "Proportion of matches",
       title = "Number of Goals per Match (TSL 2015-2016 Season)") +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 20) +
  theme(text = element_text(face = "bold"),
        legend.position = c(0.75, 0.85),
        legend.box.background = element_rect(color = "black", fill = "white"),
        legend.background = element_blank(),
        legend.box = "horizontal",
        panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, color = "black"),
        legend.key.width = unit(1.5, "cm"))
```

[image]